# Outlook performance issues when there are too many items or folders

Tags: outlook, exchangeonline, shared-mailbox

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2768656
Would the Recoverable Items folders (Versions, Purges, etcetera) be included in the 100,000 item limit described in the above KB article?

From the following article it seems the Recoverable Items are separate from the rest of the folders, but still in the same mailbox.  We have a shared mailbox where the user created folders do not exceed this 100k limit, but some of the recoverable folders do because this mailbox is currently on an In-Place hold in Exchange Online.  Opening the mailbox in OWA or in Outlook with cached mode disabled does resolve the issue.
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee364755(v=exchg.160).aspx

Comment: How big is the mailbox in general? Which Outlook client is used? Did you checked the antivirus?

Comment: Thanks BW, from Get-MailboxStatistics, the TotalItemSize is 25 GB and TotalDeletedItemSize is 100 GB.  Outlook client is 2013.  Both are irrelevant with regard to my question though.

Comment: i wouldn´t say that. I´m aware of some performence issues with Office 2010, but they do not apply here. Anyway,if the mailbox is big, then the offline cache is a big local file. I have seen that some antivirus clients scan the offline mailbox every time when it changed. Which happen nearly every 5min. So in the customer environment the Antivirus restarted to scan a single 25GB file every 5min which caused a huge performance issue as it never finished. By the way, the recoverable items folder was called["deletion dumpster"](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee364755(v=exchg.160).aspx)